# Tweets stream error SyntaxError: Unexpected token E nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I´m trying to get a stream twitter app with nodejs , apparently everything is fine but when i open more than 2 pages with the app i get this error:

```js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token E
at Object.parse(native)
at EventEmitter.receive(C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ twitter\ lib\ pa rser.js: 40: 21)
at IncomingMessage. < anonymous > (C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ twitter\ lib\ twitter.js: 207: 14)
at IncomingMessage.emit(events.js: 117: 20)
at IncomingMessage. < anonymous > (_stream_readable.js: 765: 14)
at IncomingMessage.emit(events.js: 92: 17)
at emitReadable_(_stream_readable.js: 427: 10)
at emitReadable(_stream_readable.js: 423: 5)
at readableAddChunk(_stream_readable.js: 166: 9)
at IncomingMessage.Readable.push(_stream_readable.js: 128: 10)
```

```js
//server
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;


var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/indext.html');
});
var i = 0;
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  client.stream('statuses/filter', {
    track: 'colombia'
  }, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
      console.log(tweet.text);
      i++;
      socket.emit('message', tweet.text, i);


    });
    stream.on('error', function(error) {
      throw error;

    });

  });
});

http.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('listening on %s', PORT);
});

//client

var socket = io();
$(function() {


  socket.on('message', function(msg, n) {
    $("#listamsg").append($('<br><div style="background-color:#1947A3; 

color:white;font-family:Arial; width:700px;">').text(msg));
    
    $("#num").text(n)
    $("#container").animate({
      scrollTop: $("#container")[0].scrollHeight
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Do you have high latency on your connection? I was helping someone that had this same error while I could not repro it. I opened a lot of tabs and videos to create some latency and started to repro the error. There seems to be an issue with the parsing of the data from Twitter when there's latency.

Comment: same here, what's the best way to mitigate this? I can't fix the network's latency...